# QueryDSL select count() / count() how~?

Tags: querydsl

select

```
      (select count(*) from table2 where table2.table2Seq = table1.table1Seq) as count1,

      (select count(*) from table2 where table2.table2Seq = table1.table1Seq and table2Yn = true) as count2,

      (select count(*) from table2 where table2.table2Seq = table1.table1Seq) / (select count(*) from table2 where table2.table2Seq = table1.table1Seq and table2Yn = true) as count3
```

from

```
      table1
```

order by

```
     count3
```

---

**I want this query. How do you make it into a queryDSL? I want to sort the counter from the subquery divided by the counter from the subquery.  **

```
NumberPath<Long> count1 = Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, “count1”);
NumberPath<Long> count2 = Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, “count2”);
NumberPath<Long> count3 = Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, “count3”);

JPQLQuery<OnlineTrainingCourseDto> query = getQuerydsl().createQuery()
    .select(
        new Dto(
            ExpressionUtils.as(
                JPAExpressions.select(table2.table2Seq.count())
                        .from(table2)
                        .where(table2.table2Seq.eq(table1.table1Seq)),
                count1
            ),
            ExpressionUtils.as(
                JPAExpressions.select(table2.table2Seq.count())
                        .from(table2)
                        .where(table2.table2Seq.eq(table1.table1Seq)
                        .and(table2.table2Yn.eq(true))),
                count2
            ),
            
            ***????? count1 / count2 as count3 ?????***

            )
        )
    )
    .from(table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an expression to a number expression to get access to the divide operator:

```
JPAExpressions.asNumber(
     JPAExpressions.select(table2.table2Seq.count())
                        .from(table2)
                        .where(table2.table2Seq.eq(table1.table1Seq)))
.divide(
    JPAExpressions.asNumber(JPAExpressions.select(table2.table2Seq.count())
                        .from(table2)
                        .where(table2.table2Seq.eq(table1.table1Seq)
                        .and(table2.table2Yn.eq(true))))
).as("count3")
```

Comment: Thank you so much.JPAExpressions.asNumber...  I didn't think of it.